# TDA8571J does not output a signal

Tags: amplifier, audio

I am currently trying to build an audio amplifier circuit with the TDA8571J that should run with 6V supply voltage.
This is my circuit:
[image: circuit]
The part in the middle on the left is a 5V regulatorwhich has nothing to do with this.

However when I power this up and add some signal from my mobile to the inputs 1 and 2, I don't get any output signal.
I double checked all connections and everything and have no idea what could have gone wrong.
All outputs deliver constant 3V but the audio signal is not on it.
Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated.

The datasheet for the TDA8571J can be found [here](https://www.reichelt.com/index.html?ACTION=7&LA=3&OPEN=0&INDEX=0&FILENAME=A200%2FTDA8571J%23PHI.pdf)

Comment: Pins 1 and 2 don't appear to be the audio inputs. And can you hear the relay operating?

Comment: Is the mode input properly at Vcc? What is your Vcc?

Comment: With inputs 1 and 2 I mean pins 10 and 14 of the IC over the poti and capacitors. I can hear the relay operating and my VCC is 6V as I mentioned. I use a 6V lead acid battery to power it and measure 6,3V VCC and 6,14V at the mode pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some hours of double-checking, overthinking and studying the datasheet the 100th time, I could figure out the solution by myself:

There is a hint in the datasheet on page 8:

> **Notes**
>
> 1. The circuit is DC adjusted at VP= 6 to 18 V and AC operating at VP= 8.5 to 18 V.

I interpret this as "the circuit can only enter operation condition at a Vp of 8.5V or higher" since 8.5V are also needed on the mode pin to enter working condition and I suppose it is not allowed to have a higher voltage than Vp on mode pin.

However I find it still confusing, that in the datasheet it says VpMIN = 6V as well as that the table on page 8 only tells about the mode pin voltages at Vp = 14.4V .

I tried with an extra 12V power source for the TDA8571J and it worked without any problems.